# Can I detect the build target in a build event?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I would like to detect the build target, i.e. `make` or `build`, in a build event.

I have pre-build event that compiles a number of C files into objects (.obj) which are then included in one of my Pascal files. At the moment the C files are compiled every time the pre-build event runs. I would like to be able to skip this stage if the build target is `make` and if the objects are up-to-date.

Being able to skip this stage would give me significant reductions in compile time whilst in  edit/compile/debug development mode.

So, is it possible to detect the build target?

Comment: I realize it's a bit of a hack, but why not launch the C build via a separate project-item in a project group?  If this was visual studio, it would be a '.lib' target, perhaps you can get somewhere that way.  You could even create dependencies so that the one gets built when the other is rebuilt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the IDE will only compile a single project at a time, one solution would be to register an IOTAProjectCompileNotifier. Depending on the value of CompileInfo.Mode, it could remove the build event in BeforeCompile and add it back in AfterCompile.

Comment: Thanks. If I went down that route I would set an environment variable and let the build event code modify its behaviour according to the value of that env var

Comment: I like this solution. If you detect a *compile* set an environment variable. Your build event should treat everything as a build unless the special environment variable is present: that way you're "safe" against IDE's that don't have your plugin installed.

Comment: @cosmin I guess this will do the job but it's something that should be handled by delphi itself in my view

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have just successfully implemented it.